# Mock function in mockery framework not actually mocking function

Tags: php

I am trying to use mockery framework of PHP for mocking a function. But the problem here is that mockery is not actually mocking the function but executing the function

This is the current code:

```php
$mock = Mockery::mock(MyClass::class);
$mock->shouldReceive('myFunction')
        ->with([1, 2, 3])
        ->andReturn([]);
```

`MyClass`:

```php
class MyClass {
    public function myFunction($params) {
        dd('came here');
    }
}
```

The problem here is `dd()` statement is getting executed when I execute the `Mockery` call.

Shouldn't it mock the function without actually executing the function?

Please comment if further explanation is needed

Comment: Perhaps because it is spelled `shouldReceive()` instead of `shouldRecieve()`?

Comment: No, I had corrected it before